# How to make this function neater

Tags: jquery, image, function, scaling, image-scaling

after using JS and jQuery-snippets for some years now, I wrote my own little function to replace [imagefill](http://johnpolacek.github.io/imagefill.js/%20%22imagefill.js). Do I need to be ashamed for this code or is it ok? What could I do better? Are there obvious (to your eyes) mistakes, not in the basic function - it works, after all - but in the style.

```
function fillsensible(maxWidth, maxHeight, container) {

var img = $(container).find('img');
var container = $(container);
img.css("opacity", "0");

img.load(function() {
    var ratio = 0;
    var containerHeight = container.height();
    var containerWidth = container.width();

    if(img.width() > maxWidth) {
        ratio = maxWidth / img.width();
        img.css("width", maxWidth);
        img.css("height", img.height() * ratio); // Scale height based on ratio
    } else if (img.height() > maxHeight) {
        ratio = maxHeight / img.height();
        img.css("height", maxHeight);
        img.css("width", img.width() * ratio); // Scale height based on ratio
    };

    container.css('position', 'relative');
    img.css('position', 'absolute');
    marginTop = (containerHeight - img.height())/2;
    marginLeft = (containerWidth - img.width())/2;  
    img.css({
      "top": marginTop,
      "left": marginLeft,
      "opacity": "1"
    });
});
}
```

If not clear from the start: This looks into a given container element in the DOM for an img, scales it proportionally to its original size to a given maximum size in pixels and positions it at the center of the container.

This is all easy with background images but impossible with img-elements to my knowledge.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: This question is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ok, sorry. I didn't know about codereview, until now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Besides you dont need to adjust height of any img element

the code could simply be

```
function fillsensible(maxWidth, maxHeight, container) {

var img = $(container).find('img');
var container = $(container);
img.css("opacity", "0");

img.load(function() {
    var ratio = 0;
    var containerHeight = container.height();
    var containerWidth = container.width();

    if(img.width() > maxWidth) {
        ratio = maxWidth / img.width();
        img.css("width", maxWidth);
        img.css("height", "auto"); // Scale height based on ratio
    } else if (img.height() > maxHeight) {
        ratio = maxHeight / img.height();
        img.css("height", maxHeight);
        img.css("width", "auto"); // Scale height based on ratio
    };

    container.css('position', 'relative');
    marginTop = (containerHeight - img.height())/2;
    marginLeft = (containerWidth - img.width())/2;  
    img.css({
      "position": "absolute"
      "top": marginTop,
      "left": marginLeft,
      "opacity": "1"
    });
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

marginTop and marginLeft variables should be declared locally

```
var marginLeft, marginTop;
```

Comment: Do you mind telling me why that is? I always thought the strength in javascript vars is that they can be initialized implicit.

Comment: If they're not declared with var keyword they become global and you could override something elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Neater code below, I removed redundant code.

```
function fillsensible(maxWidth, maxHeight, container) {

    var container = $(container).css('position', 'relative'),
        img = container.find('img').css({"opacity": 0, 'position': 'absolute'});

    img.load(function() {
        var ratio = 0,
            containerHeight = container.height(),
            containerWidth = container.width(),
            marginLeft, marginTop;

        if(img.width() > maxWidth) {
            ratio = maxWidth / img.width();
            img.css({ 
                "width": maxWidth,
                "height": img.height() * ratio
            });
        } else if (img.height() > maxHeight) {
            ratio = maxHeight / img.height();
            img.css({
                "height": maxHeight,
                "width": img.width() * ratio
            });
        };

        marginTop = (containerHeight - img.height())/2;
        marginLeft = (containerWidth - img.width())/2;  
        img.css({
          "top": marginTop,
          "left": marginLeft,
          "opacity": 1
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I see what you did there.

Answer (score 0):

One neat thing could be to make it a plugin. For example :

```
(function($) {

    function fillsensible(maxWidth, maxHeight, container) {
        // your previous code
    }

    $.fn.fillsensible = function(maxWidth, maxHeight) {
        fillsensible(maxWidth, maxHeight, this);
        return this;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

So you can use it this way and chain other function calls to the container element

```
$("#container").fillsensible(100, 200);
```

Comment: If you are going to make it into a plugin, you should instead use configurable options instead of function parameters.

Comment: Ok, I see. This is indeed nicer to use. Thanks for the idea.
I will explore the ways of plugin-authoring.